# Playback problems with FLV that is transferred via PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flv

I am facing the following problem: I'd like to keep people from downloading FLV-files from a site (yes, I do know that they will get them if they really want them in the end, never mind that) so I wanted to put them outside my htdocs and "transfer" them via PHP.

For this I am using a rather simple chunk of code:

```
//Generate $filename here
header('Content-Disposition: filename=video.flv');
header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
readfile($filename);
```

This works perfectly fine when I just call the PHP and I get the FLV that I want, but as soon as I pass this to the swf that is supposed to load the video, things stop working and nothing happens at all (I can see in my "Tools" that the browser indeed downloads the whole video, but the swf just won't start playing it). I suspect this has something to do with the swf thinking "This ain't no FLV", but I have no clue why.
The header information that is sent with the transferred file are perfectly fine btw.

Anyone any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't pass the FLV through PHP, which headers does your server return when the file is requested by the SWF? Can you give the request headers as well? I'm asking for this because I assume that some response headers might be missing when you pass the FLV through your PHP.

Comment: Try to comment out header `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, the strange this is that when I call for the original FLV file the headers (both request and response) are completely blank (at least that's what Chrome Dev Tools are telling me). The headers for the PHP look like this:

Comment: Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.mysite.com
Referer:myswf.swf
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.77 Safari/534.24

Comment: and: Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:filename=video.flv
Content-Type:video/x-flv
Date:Tue, 07 Jun 2011 11:31:31 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=194
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17

Comment: Ok everyone,
I do not have any clue why this made the final difference, but this is what I changed to make it work.

When I set things up I passed the filename using $_GET so I could easily test things, but since I am using $_SESSION now for passing the filename, things work just fine. No difference in the header, nothing. Just the way I passed a "01".

I am glad this is working now, but has anyone any clue what the "logic" behind this may be?

Comment: if you have more info, update your question instead of posting comments, they're pretty hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but maybe the player relies on the `Content-Length` header, which it appears you're not sending.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I already tried this and it does not make any difference at all. But maybe I should include this nonetheless to avoid other possible issues!